# Access the canvas name in WPF in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF and are following tutorials online. I was trying to use the canvas name in the code-behind as it was in the tutorial but it's saying "the name doesn't exist in current context"

I have tried the visual studio suggestions but it resulted in further problems.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Snake_Game.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Snake_Game"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Snake Game - Score: 0" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
            <Canvas x:Name="GameArea" ClipToBounds="True" Width="400" Height="400">

            </Canvas>
        </Border>
</Window>
```

```
namespace Snake_Game
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const int SnakeSquareSize = 20;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawGameArea();
        }

        private void DrawGameArea()
        {
            bool doneDrawingBackground = false;
            int nextX = 0, nextY = 0;
            int rowCounter = 0;
            bool nextIsOdd= false;

            while (doneDrawingBackground == false)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
                {
                    Width = SnakeSquareSize,
                    Height = SnakeSquareSize,
                    Fill = nextIsOdd ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black
                };

                GameArea.Children.Add(rect);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The window markup specifies`x:Class="Snake_Game.MainWindow"` for the code behind, but it isn't clear whether `MainWindow` in the `Snake_Game` namespace. If it in some other namespace (or no namespace) the XAML wont be considered part of the same object, leading to the `GameArea` being undefined in the code.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the code-behind so hopefully it is clear now. If I'm not wrong `MainWindow` is in the `Snake_Game` namespace?

Comment: Do you get an exception? I assume this is just a compiler warning that will get resolved after a build/clean+rebuild. You should also consider to handle the Loaded event instead of the ContentRendered event. If Intellisense is suggesting the correct name in the editor then it should work after a clean+rebuild.

Comment: What happened when you corrected the code? When I cut and paste everything into a project, the problem does not occur.